# which hibernate query language is more efficient

Tags: java, hibernate

According to hibernate doc

from Cat as cat where cat.id = 123

from Cat as cat where cat.mate.id = 69

The second query is efficient and does not require a table join.

I think first query will not require table join and second query will require inner join.
Kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

These are examples of SQL which will be generated from your HQL

The first (`from Cat as cat where cat.id = 123`):

```
select c.* from Cat c where c.id=123;
// no joins - OK
```

The second (`from Cat as cat where cat.mate.id = 69`):

```
select c.* from Cat c where c.mate_id=69;
// no joins (because cat.mate.id is the identifier in Mate)
// that's why it's efficient
```

If you had this HQL: `"from Cat as cat where cat.mate.name = 'mate'"` the SQL would look like:

```
select c.* from Cat c join Mate m on c.mate_id = m.id where m.name='mate';
```

`c.mate_id` is a foregn key which references to Mate's `id` column

Comment: @user872487 Both queries DO NOT require joins. Please look at my answer more carefully. And the documentation doesn't state that the second query is MORE efficient, it says that the second query is efficient as it doesn't require a join.

Comment: @user872487 And the first query is more efficient because you're searching by primary key and it returns only one row (or zero). In the second query you're searching by foreign key, the query may return more then one rows. But you don't need a join because there is enough information in Cat table to produce the result.